# IP throttling on web app (app service)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a few webpages (aspx) hosted in the Azure web app (app service), this is already in production. We observed that appeared to be some abnormal activities that seems hacker access that accessing the app intensively between milliseconds. How can we avoid this kind of activities, by introducing IP rate throttling (e.g. traffic from a single IP can only allow to access the page 1 time per minute).

Is this something could be done by app service alone or have to introduce other azure services? We have an azure API Management service, we also think to put it behind there but that seems overkill..

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014808/limit-concurrent-requests-in-azure-app-service out, it might be useful for your scenario.

Answer (score -3):

If your requirement fits, see if you could leverage Azure Application Insights to tackle this - Find out when people use your web app, what pages they're most interested in, where your users are located, and what browsers and operating systems they use. Analyze business and usage telemetry by using. See, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-segmentation#querying-for-certain-users

Application Insights automatically analyzes the telemetry generated by your application and detects potential security issues. This capability enables you to identify potential security problems and handle them by fixing the application or by taking the necessary security measures.

You can further check suspicious activity, see the document How do I fix the "Suspicious user activity" detection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-proactive-application-security-detection-pack#how-do-i-fix-the-insecure-url-access-detection

Reference: Usage analysis with Application Insights: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-overview