# Reducing maximum concurrent requests on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Cloud Service (classic) that performs a lengthy operation for a request. If the traffic suddenly increases dramatically, I would rather the cloud service not be slowed to the speed of a snail by trying to serve all the requests at once. So the natural solution to me seems to be to simply reject new requests if the number of concurrent requests is too high (for my application it it is better if some of the requests are rejected than all of them slowed down massively).

For ASP.NET there seems to be a capability to do this through `<system.web>`:

```
<system.web>
<applicationPool 
    maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="30"
    maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0"
    requestQueueLimit="30" 
/>
</system.web>
```

However this doesn't seem to work for me, all requests then fail without clear error message. And besides Visual Studio is telling me that the tag is not expected. So I would guess this isn't available for Azure Cloud Services.

What can I do here to achieve this for an Azure Cloud Service? I would also be interested in something like limiting the maximum request time. The only thing I can think of is to actually try to count the requests in the C# code but that definitely seems suboptimal.

I am using .NET 4.6.1 and when RDPing into the cloud service VM the IIS version seems to be 10.0 (from looking at the manager).

I have seen the answer to this question: [Limit concurrent requests in Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014808/limit-concurrent-requests-in-azure-app-service) . However that is not what I want as I do not want to block IP addresses at any stage.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this, DenverCoder9?