# .NET 5 Service hosted in Azure very slow at times

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, .net-5

I have some performance problems with an application that I can't seem to find out why happens.

The application is a .NET 5 application hosted as a Azure Web App. The app is a very large one thousand of code lines in total, and a round 1000 concurrent users. I'm not really sure how to give the correct details, but I'll happily provide whatever you request.

What happens is that request response time usually lay in the 20-50ms for most requests.

But some times during the day, for some responses it can take up to a couple of minutes, and that lasts for some minutes, and then back to normal.

When checking the database during that time, everything seems normal. No large spikes in db, and also checking app insights for the time period, the db calls seems to take a few milliseconds.

What is strange is that is seems that the time is lost for timeouts/awaiting/whatever. IP had a call that does two http calls to other services using async await, and in the app insights logs, the first call is done in 20 ms, and the second is done in 20 ms, but the total methos used 1.5 minutes. And the timestamp between the first and second http request makes it look like the app waited 1.5 minutes after the first call before doing the second call.

Could it be something like all the asp.net app thread being used up? I could not find out what is the max cocurrent threads in a .net 5 app hosted in Azure Web Apps anywhere. What happens with async/await if there are no available threads when the awaited task is done?

CPU and memory for the service is not at all maxed out during this time, but are at around 20-30%.

Any other idea of what could cause this very strange behaviour? Any data you need me to provide?

This is the graph for response time in Azure that clearly show these spikes happen fairly often.

[image]

Comment: hi, I can suggest few things like add granular level logs for methods and in finally block  of each method add time duration it took to execute. This will give list of methods which are taking more time to execute. Then review those methods to check if async await is implemented in correct manner or not.

As you mentioned, there are 1000 concurrent users access sites. So, can you share which app service plan you are using?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement , Based on this [***Troubleshot MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation)

There are below root cause:

- Network requests taking a long time .
- Application code or database queries being inefficient .
- Application using high memory orCPU .
- Application crashing due to an exception .

Please refer the above  provided MS DOC for troubleshot .

- ***For Concurrent limitation its depend on the plan we are using***
  According to this [***GitHub link***](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/azure-websites-limits.md#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20maximum%20concurrent%20requests,(18%2C750%20x%204%20cores).)  ,

> if we scale an app in the Basic tier to two instances, each of the two
> instances will have 350 concurrent connections.
>
> And Web sockets have no theoretical limits in the Standard tier and
> above, however other factors can limit the number of web sockets.
>
> For example:- the maximum concurrent requests per CPU are 7,500 per
> small VM, 15,000 per medium VM (7,500 x 2 cores), and 75,000 per large
> VM (specified by maxConcurrentRequestsPerCpu) (18,750 x 4 cores).

For  more information Please refer the below links:

- [***MS Q&A Thread***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/331380/slow-azure-web-app-loading-aspnet-mvc-app.html)
- [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014808/limit-concurrent-requests-in-azure-app-service)